# Driver automated code directs back to the starting URL

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Here is the code that opens the site and fills up the PNR value and loads the invoice. After it clicks on the invoice instead of directing to the invoice details, it directs back to the start URL

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe') # Get local session(use webdriver.Chrome() for chrome) 
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("url") # load page from some url

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='PNRId']").send_keys("HI19GJ")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='GstRetrievePageInteraction']").click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
element=driver.find_element_by_link_text('View Invoice')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Sometimes the above code opens up correctly the page that should open after clicking the view invoice tab and sometimes it directs to the starting page. Why does this happen? Can anyone guide me on this?

The Start page URL:
[Start URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBXFq.png)

The Invoice Retrieved image:
[Invoice Generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnpV5.png)

The HTML code for View Invoice:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSBdk.png)

If I use this code `element=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href*="GSTInvoice"]') driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)` It shows Browser not compatible and the link it the one that contains the Invoice but I can't view it.

Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: Can you tell the site url?

Comment: Hi Karthik, https://book.goindigo.in/Booking/GSTInvoiceDetails is the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the snippet. It worked for me everytime when I find element using `name` tag. It should work for you too.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name('ViewInvoice')
element.click();
```

**Edit**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe') # Get local session(use webdriver.Chrome() for chrome) 
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get("https://book.goindigo.in/Booking/GSTInvoiceDetails") # load page from some url
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='PNRId']").send_keys("HI19GJ")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='GstRetrievePageInteraction']").click()
element = driver.find_element_by_name('ViewInvoice')
element.click()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221340/discussion-on-answer-by-karthik-driver-automated-code-directs-back-to-the-starti).